# How to prove that $1/ ((y+z) x^4) + 1/ ((z+x) y^4) + 1/ ((x+y) z^4) \geq 3/2$ for $x, y, z>0$ such that $xyz=1$?

Tags: inequalities, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How to prove that $\dfrac{1}{(y+z) x^4} + \dfrac{1}{(x+z) y^4} + \dfrac{1}{(y+x) z^4}\geq3/2$ for $x, y, z>0$, such that $xyz=1$?

Comment: Why are you sure it is true? What is the source of the question?

Comment: TeX note: `\cfrac` is meant for continued fractions, like $\cfrac1{1 + \cfrac1 1}$ `\cfrac1{1 + \cfrac1 1}` (nested as needed).  If, as here, you just want to force displaystyle, then you can manually switch it on with $\displaystyle\frac1{(y + z)x^4}$ `\displaystyle\frac1{(y + z)x^4}` (as compared to $\frac1{(y + z)x^4}$ `\frac1{(y + z)x^4}`), or use the shortcut $\dfrac1{(y + z)x^4}$ `\dfrac1{(y + z)x^4}`.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: Is this from an ongoing contest?

Comment: The source of the question and whether it is from an ongoing contest are irrelevant. What is obvious is that this question does not fit the MO profile. I do not understand why it has already received two answers (and from high reputation users!), and I also do not understand why those answers have been upvoted. Closure (and deletion?) should be the only destiny of this question.

Comment: Around the same time, Jogn posted exactly the same question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581269 (to which there are currently two seemingly correct answers).

Comment: @AlexM. : The question is not motivated at all and therefore deserves criticisms. However, among other things, it gives us a chance to familiarize some users with useful techniques (used in many actual publications) and/or with some clever, possibly surprising uses of well-known tools.

Comment: @AlexM. A long time ago, when trying to construct non-trivial cohomology classes for certain Banach algebras, I managed to reduce the problem down to trying to solve multivariate inequalities of a similar nature to the one here. Are we having one of these instances yet again where it turns out that I should give back my PhD because I don't do proper mathematics, or something?

Comment: @YemonChoi: There are many other instances of high-level mathematics that depend, at some point, on the solution of some high-school-level inequality. What I am saying is that these inequalities should be isolated from the greater problem in which they appeared and asked about on MSE. No need for irony.

Comment: @AlexM. : "What I am saying is that these inequalities should be isolated from the greater problem in which they appeared and asked about on MSE." Why?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Tautologically because this is precisely why MSE was created: in the beginning there was just MO, but because very high-level questions were mixed with elementary ones, it was decided to discharge the more elementary content of MO onto MSE.

Comment: @AlexM. : I don't see this "very high-level questions" vs. "elementary ones" matter anywhere in the MO mission statement. What I see (at https://mathoverflow.net/help) is this: "we are a community of mathematicians focused on asking and answering **mathematical questions related to current research in mathematics**."

Comment: Previous comment continued: "So, "related" (say, by the use of such "elementary" inequalities themselves or by the use of methods of their proofs in serious enough publications) is fine. I see nothing in the guidelines that says that "these [...] should be isolated from the greater problem" or anything like that.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Not everything that is understood is also explicitly written; it is not written in the constitution that two people who meet should greet each other. Every community (including MO) is built around a set of written rules and a set of unwritten rules, this is a basic sociollogical truth.

Comment: @AlexM. : Has it ever occurred to you that different people may legitimately understand differently what is "not explicitly written"? Or that you yourself might have seriously misunderstood what is "not explicitly written"? No doubts about that? Anyhow, again, it appears that, by what it **is written**, "related" (say, by the use of such "elementary" inequalities themselves or by the use of methods of their proofs in serious enough publications) is fine.

Comment: @AlexM. I don't agree with your characterization of the difference between MO and MSE; *non-research-level mathematics* does not belong on MO, but *elementary* is not the same as *non-research level*. The elementary proof of the prime number theorem was a major research achievement. At the same time, I agree that this question is a bad fit for MO as it stands---not because it is elementary, but because its connection to research-level mathematics is unclear.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem comes to mind: A completely elementary statement, initially motivated apparently by nothing but curiosity, whose value seems to be almost entirely in broadly useful methods of the proof. The situation with the question on this page seems similar, even if on a much, much lesser scale.

Comment: This user Jogn altogether asked two questions at MO without any context within two days which both very much look like typical math contest problems. I think we should refrain from helping people cheat.

Comment: @PeterMueller : Interesting. I didn't even think about a possibility of cheating. Anyway, I think the solutions in my answer are hardly of math-contest types. :-)

Comment: @PeterMueller : I also think any answer to any question could be used inappropriately, in principle. It would be hard to follow all such uses, even if one wanted to. However, I know at least one case when the entire proof in my answer was incorporated into a paper, whereas I was only thanked there in general "for discussion", without mentioning my role in that specific proof at all. So, this problem seems, not so much about the kind of question, but about the kind of use of answers to the question, over which we have very little control.

Answer (score 9):

$\newcommand\tH{\tilde H}$This problem is one of real algebraic geometry, which can be solved purely algorithmically. In Mathematica, such algorithms are implemented by `Reduce` and similar commands.

Here is a solution with Mathematica:

[image]

---

Here is a "more human" proof: Let $f(x,y,z)$ stand for the left-hand side of your desired inequality. We want to show that $f(x,y,z)\ge3/2$ if $x,y,z>0$ and $xyz=1$. Equivalently, we want to show that
$$h(x,y):=\big(f(x,y,\tfrac1{xy})-\tfrac32\big)
2 x^3 y^3 (x + y) (1 + x^2 y) (1 + x y^2) \\ 
=2 x^{10} y^{10}+2 x^9 y^8+2 x^8 y^9+2 x^7 y^7-3 x^7 y^6-3 x^6 y^7-3 x^6
   y^4+2 x^6 y^2-6 x^5 y^5+2 x^5 y^3+2 x^5-3 x^4 y^6-3 x^4 y^3+2 x^4
   y+2 x^3 y^5-3 x^3 y^4+2 x^2 y^6+2 x y^4+2 y^5\overset{\text{(?)}}\ge0$$
for $x,y>0$.

Consider the partial derivatives $p(x,y):=h_x(x,y)$ and $q(x,y):=h_y(x,y)$. Let $r_1(y)$ and $r_2(x)$ denote the resultants of the polynomials $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$ w.r. to $x$ and $y$, respectively. By symmetry, the real roots of $r_1(y)$ and $r_2(x)$ are the same: $z_1:=0$, $z_2:=1$, and a certain algebraic number $z_3\approx0.8180077783$. Therefore the critical points of $h$ in $(0,\infty)^2$ (if any) are of the form $(z_j,z_k)$ for $j,k\in\{2,3\}$. It is straightforward to check that $h(z_j,z_k)\ge0$ for $j,k\in\{2,3\}$.

So, it remains to check that the boundary values of $h$, near the boundary of the set $[0,\infty]^2$, are $\ge0$.

We have $h(0,y)=2 y^5\ge0$ for $y\ge0$ and $h(x,0)=2x^5\ge0$ for $x\ge0$. This does it for the boundary pieces $\{0\}\times[0,\infty)$ and  $[0,\infty)\times\{0\}$.

By symmetry, it remains to show that $\liminf_{x,y\to\infty}h(x,y)\ge0$ and $\liminf_{y\to0,x\to\infty}h(x,y)\ge0$.
Let
$$H_{11}(x,y):=h(\tfrac1x,\tfrac1y)x^{10}y^{10}
=2+2 x^{10} y^5+2 x^9 y^6+2 x^8 y^4-3 x^7 y^6+2 x^7 y^5+2 x^6 y^9-3 x^6
   y^7-3 x^6 y^4+2 x^5 y^{10}+2 x^5 y^7-6 x^5 y^5+2 x^4 y^8-3 x^4 y^6-3
   x^4 y^3-3 x^3 y^4+2 x^3 y^3+2 x^2 y+2 x y^2.$$
Obviously, $H_{11}(0+,0+)=2>0$. So, $\liminf_{x,y\to\infty}h(x,y)\ge0$.

Let
$$H_{01}(x,y):=h(\tfrac1x,y)x^{10}
=2 x^{10} y^5+2 x^9 y^4+2 x^8 y^6+2 x^7 y^5-3 x^7 y^4-3 x^6 y^6-3 x^6
   y^3+2 x^6 y-6 x^5 y^5+2 x^5 y^3+2 x^5-3 x^4 y^7-3 x^4 y^4+2 x^4
   y^2+2 x^3 y^7-3 x^3 y^6+2 x^2 y^9+2 x y^8+2 y^{10}.$$
Removing from the latter expression terms dominated by other terms whenever $x,y\to0$, we end up with having to show that $\liminf_{x,y\to0}\tH(x,y)\ge0$, where
$$\tH(x,y):=(2+o(1)) x^5 + (2+o(1)) x^4 y^2 - (3+o(1)) x^3 y^6 + 2 x y^8 + 2 x^2 y^9 + 2 y^{10},$$
which follows because
$$(2+o(1)) x^4 y^2 - (3+o(1)) x^3 y^6 + 2 x y^8 \\
\ge(2+o(1)) x^5 y^4 - (3+o(1)) x^3 y^6 + 2 x y^8 \\ 
=x y^8[(2+o(1)) s^4 - (3+o(1)) s^2 + 2 ]>0$$
for all small enough $x,y>0$, where $s:=x/y$.
So, $\liminf_{y\to0,x\to\infty}h(x,y)\ge0$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thanks! Does mathematica also show the proof of the inequality?

Comment: Now there is a "more human" proof.

Answer (score 9):

Is the "cauchy-schwarz-inequality" tag a guess or a hint? . . .

At any rate, it turns out to be a good start.  Let
$$
R := \frac1{(y+z) x^4} + \frac1{(z+x) y^4} + \frac1{(x+y) z^4}.
$$
We show $xyz = 1 \Rightarrow R > 3/2$, with equality if and only if
$(x,y,z) = (1,1,1)$.  By Cauchy-Schwarz, $RS \geq T^2$, where
$$
S := (y+z) x + (z+x) y + (x+y) z,
$$ $$
T := \frac1{x^{3/2}} + \frac1{y^{3/2}} + \frac1{z^{3/2}}.
$$
Note that
$$
S = 2(yz + zx + xy) = 2\left(\frac1x + \frac1y + \frac1z\right);
$$
because $xyz = 1$; in particular, $S \geq 6$ by the AM-GM inequality,
with equality $\Leftrightarrow (x,y,z) = (1,1,1)$.
By weighted AM-GM,
$$
2 \frac1{x^{3/2}} + 1 \geq \frac3x
$$
with equality $\Leftrightarrow x = 1$, and likewise for $y$ and $z$.
Therefore
$$
2T \geq \frac32 S - 3,
$$
and it remains to prove that
$$
S \geq 6 \Rightarrow \frac14 \left(\frac32 S - 3\right)^2 \geq \frac32 S
$$
with equality $\Leftrightarrow S = 6$.
But this is clear from the factorization
$$
\frac14 \left(\frac32 S - 3\right)^2 - \frac32 S = \frac3{16} (S-6) (3S-2)
$$
since $S \geq 6 \Rightarrow 3S-2 \geq 16 > 0$.  **QED**